# How to increase circle width and image width in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I have three circles filled with an image each. When click on a button a random circles becomes bigger. The problem is that the image doesn't work properly. I would like to make the picture to be 100% of the circle:

[image]

I cannot make the image to be same size as the circle. 
Here is the code for creating the defs, pattern, image and circle:

```
group.append("g")
    .attr('id', 'a' + d.uuid)
    .append('defs')
    .append("svg:pattern")
    .attr("id", 'img'+ d.uuid)
    .attr("width", config.avatar_size)
    .attr("height", config.avatar_size)
    .attr("patternUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
    .append("svg:image")
    .attr("xlink:href", d.img)
    .attr("width", config.avatar_size)
    .attr("height", config.avatar_size)
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)


    d3.select('#a' + d.uuid).append('circle')
    .attr("cx", (config.avatar_size/2) + i * 48)
    .attr("cy", config.avatar_size/2)
    .attr("r", config.avatar_size/2)
    .style("fill", "#fff")
    .style("fill", "url(#img" + d.uuid + ")")
    .attr('stroke', 'black')
    .attr("stroke-width", "2");
```

And here is the onclick event:

```
function getRandom(max)
{
   var s = d3.select('#a'+max).attr('cx');
   console.log("cx is: " + s);
   d3.select('#a'+max)
       .transition()
       .duration(1000)
       .attr('transform', 'translate(' + (-s + 150) + ', 150)')
       .select('circle')
       .attr('r', (config.avatar_size + 20)/2)

d3.select('#img' + max)
    .attr('width', config.avatar_size + 20)
    .attr('height', config.avatar_size + 20)
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0);

d3.select('#img'+ max + ' image')
    .attr('width', config.avatar_size + 20)
    .attr('height', config.avatar_size + 20)
}
```

And Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: It looks like your image went bigger, wich is what you wanted, but the offset is somewhat wrong because you tried to center it when it was smaller

Comment: Thanks. I observed that only first image is positioned properly. And don't know what is the reason. I apply one code for all beacons.